# Javascript Object Jquery callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, object, callback

In an object I have a method where I want to get some information from a server(JSON format). I want to add this data to my object where the function is (By using a setter).
The problem is that this isn't my object but the jquery callback. How could/should I solve this?

```
function anObject() {

    $.get(URL, doTheCallback); 
    function setExample(example) {    
        this.example = example;
    }

    function doTheCallback(data) {
        this.setExample(data.results[0].example);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `bind`:

```
$.get(URL,doTheCallback.bind(this));
```

> The [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method creates a new function that, when called, has its
>   this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of
>   arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

Or assign your scope in a variable like:

```
function anObject() {
    var that = this;

    $.get(URL, doTheCallback); 

    function setExample(example) {    
        that.example = example;
    }

    function doTheCallback(data) {
        that.setExample(data.results[0].example);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the second one* work with prototype too?

I get an refference error when I use prototype:
ReferenceError: that is not defined

Answer (score 1):

If you switched to `$.ajax`, you can use the context option.

```
function anObject() {
    $.ajax(URL, {context: this}).done(doTheCallback); 
    function setExample(example) {    
        this.example = example;
    }

    function doTheCallback(data) {
        this.setExample(data.results[0].example);
    }
}
```